# Why would after a finite number of steps we will end up with disjoint sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

I know this question will get a lot of downvotes but pardon me because after thinking about it in many ways, I can't see why I would end up with disjoint sets after a finite number of steps. Now I state my problem.

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measured space. Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,...,A_n\in\Sigma$ and let $c_i,c_2,c_3,...,c_n\in(0,\infty)$. Define a quantity $h$ as
$$h=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\mu(A_i).$$

$\textbf{Step 1}$

Let's find two sets $A_j,A_k\ (j\neq k)$ such that $A_j\cap A_k\neq\emptyset$. Then $A_j=A_j\setminus A_k\cup (A_j\cap A_k)$, $A_k=A_k\setminus A_j\cup (A_j\cap A_k)$. It is obvious that $A_j\setminus A_k,\ A_k\setminus A_j,\ A_j\cap A_k\in\Sigma$.

$\textbf{Step 2}$

Rewrite the quantity $h$ as
$$h=\sum_{i\in [n]\setminus\{j,k\}}c_i\mu(A_i)+ c_j\mu(A_j\setminus A_k)+ c_k\mu(A_k\setminus A_j)+ (c_j+c_k)\mu(A_j\cap A_k).$$

$\textbf{Repeat Step 1 and Step 2}$

Now, my question is, how can I prove that after a finite number of steps, we will end up $h$ in the form
$$h=\sum_{i=1}^{m}d_i\mu(B_i),$$
where $d_i\in(0,\infty)$ and $\forall p,q\in[m]\ (p\neq q)$ we have that $B_p\cap B_q=\emptyset.$

Can somebody prove it by contradiction or any other method?

Comment: There is only a finite number of patterns of the form "belong to the sets $A_{i_1},\ldots,A_{i_s}$ but not to the remaining ones".  So $m=2^n$ is sufficient.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Look at all the regions in the Venn diagram of the $A_i$s.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek ; I can't visualize the Venn diagram of more than three sets.

Comment: I can't either. Start with 2, 3 sets, understand what is going on, and generalize.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Venn diagram suggestion from the comments written out more formally

$$\sum_{i=1,\ldots,n}c_i \mu(A_i) = \sum_{I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}}\left(\left(\sum_{i\in I}c_i\right) \cdot \mu\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\setminus\bigcup_{j\not\in I}A_j\right)\right). $$